# If $T$ has a continuous inverse, then $R_T$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, open-map

Let $T$ be a continuous (thus bounded) linear map from a Banach space $X$ to a Banach space $Y$. I want to prove that if $T$ has a continuous inverse, then $R_T$ is closed, where $R_T=T(X)$ is the range of $T$.

Attempt: We recall that $R_T$ is closed if its complement is open or equivalently $R_T$ is closed if it contains all its limit points. Further we recall that a function with inverse is both injective and surjective. I thought, perhaps naively, that since the function $T$ is a bijection we have that $R_T$ is all of $Y$ and hence the complement of $R_T$ is the empty set which is always open and closed in any topology. But then we don't use that the inverse of $T$ is continuous so this reasoning is probably wrong.

I also considered if we may use the open mapping theorem which say that because $T^{-1}$ is a bounded (since continuous) surjective map between Banach spaces, it maps open sets in $Y$ surjectively to open sets in $X$. But I couldn't come up an argument.

How to solve the problem?

Comment: It seems the assumption is that $T:X\to T(X)$ has a bounded inverse.

Comment: Yes that is the assumption. Since it is assumed that the inverse i continuous that is equivalent to it being bounded if I understood things correctly.

Comment: Then $\|T^{-1}(Tx)\|\le \|T^{-1}\|\|Tx\|,$ i.e. $\|x\|\le |T^{-1}\|\|Tx\|.$ The last inequality implies that the range $T(X)$ is closed.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Thank you but why does the last inequality imply that the range is closed? Maybe it is obvious but don't see it directly.

Comment: Please edit your post to clarify it like Ryszard formulated in his first comment, otherwise your question is trivial (if $T$ has an inverse, i.e. if $T$ is a bijection from $X$ to $Y,$ then $T(X)=Y$).

Comment: The proof can be found in many textbooks. If $Tx_n$ is convergent, say to  $y,$ then it satisfies the Cauchy condition. The inequality implies that $x_n$ satisfies the Cauchy condition, hence is convergent, say to $x.$ Thus $Tx_n$ is convergent to $Tx,$ i.e. $Tx=y.$

Comment: @Anne Bauval: But isn't the inverse being a continuous function equivalent to it being a bounded function? That is for example what Friedman Foundations of Modern Analysis th. 4.4.2 says. I be happy to edit the question but I don't understand why it is wrong as currently phrased.

Comment: As currently phrased, it is not wrong but obvious. Again: because your hypothesis "$T$ has a continuous inverse" is too strong; it means: "$T:X\to Y$ is bijective and $T^{-1}$ is continuous", instead of what you really want to say and was formulated in the 1st comment above.